# Using an existing Django project in a new Docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, django, container

I am trying to start a Docker container using a Django project in the same directory.

Following this tutorial,
https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#create-a-django-project,
it is possible to use

```
docker-compose run web django-admin startproject newproject .
```

to start the project from inside the docker container defined in the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    #command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn things.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: NGINXDOCKERNAME
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

and dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
VOLUME /code
```

How do you use django-admin startproject newproject . from outside the container (ie from the docker-machine command line) and then to copy the project into the container?

Now, if I start the project inside the container the server starts and I can see my project at the right port but if I start the project outside the container (but in the same directory locally) the web and nginx containers do not correctly start.

I am running a docker-machine on windows 10 version 1709.

The output from the web container startup is below followed by the output of the server on request.

Cheers

`Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
web_1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
web_1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/init.py", line 130, in connect
web_1    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1    | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1    |      Is the server running on host "db" (172.19.0.2) and accepting
web_1    |      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1    |
web_1    |
web_1    | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1    |
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "manage.py", line 22, in 
web_1    |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
web_1    |     utility.execute()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 356, in execute
web_1    |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
web_1    |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
web_1    |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 110, in handle
web_1    |     loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 282, in check_consistent_history
web_1    |     applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
web_1    |     self.ensure_schema()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
web_1    |     if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
web_1    |     return self._cursor()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
web_1    |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in exit
web_1    |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
web_1    |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
web_1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
web_1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/init.py", line 130, in connect
web_1    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1    |      Is the server running on host "db" (172.19.0.2) and accepting
web_1    |      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Server output

`NGINXDOCKERNAME | 2017/11/21 19:56:28 [error] 5#5: *1 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.3:8000/polls/", host: "192.168.99.100:8000"`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found in https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database. If you actually set your database as explained in the link, such that your DATABASE config becomes:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

am sure you will have no problem whatsoever.

Another thing you can do is to set `listen_addresses = '*'` using vim. Try this link http://www.mozmorris.com/2011/11/15/configure-postgresql-to-accept-tcpip-connections.html for more information on that